# React Redux using many smart containers and structuring components

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been used to writing code where I had a giant smart container and would pass some props down to the children who need it. However, I've been starting to try a different approach of just creating more containers that grab whatever info they need from the store.

Let's say I have a parent div and three children divs. Parent div is connected and has whatever props it needs. Some child divs also have some functionality and props that it needs.

Basically, is this a normal/good way of approaching things? Just wanted to make sure I'm not doing this the wrong way or creating too many smart containers is a bad thing.

```
<ConnectedParent>
  <ConnectedChild>
  <ConnectedChild>
  <PresentationalChild>
</ConnectedParent>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the Redux FAQ entry on ["Should I only connect my top component, or can I connect multiple components in my tree?"](https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#should-i-only-connect-my-top-component-or-can-i-connect-multiple-components-in-my-tree).

Basically, feel free to connect as many components as you want, and connecting more components usually leads to better performance.

Comment: Wow i read through some of the documentation but don't know how I missed this. Thanks a lot! Definitely going to just go through everything here more thoroughly next time.

Comment: Yeah, we plan to revamp the docs later this year, and we'll try to highlight this more in the process.